# How to export canvas image which is decorated html5 function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cors

I'm a JavaScript beginner.
I want to export canvas as png image which is decorated(being drawn some text with fillText).

But I can't because of the following error.

```
Script from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm happy if you some advice.

The following is my source code

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="myscript.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>draw text to loaded image</h1>
<form>
<input type="button" value="draw on canvas" onclick="draw()">
</form>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<!-- <form>
<input type="button" value="export to image" onclick="chgImg()">
</form> -->
<div><img id="newImg"></div>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

## myscript.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(){
  var img = new Image();
  //load local image
  img.src = 'test.png';
  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  }
  ctx.font = 'bold 20px Verdana';
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText('test', 20, 20, 200);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("newImg").src = dataURL;
  console.log(dataURL);
  chgImg();
}

// export to png
function chgImg() {
  var png = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("newImg").src = png;
}
```

Comment: Most likely you load your page as a local file which cause security concerns in most browsers. You have to place it on a web server.

Comment: Thanks @hindmost for your advice. 
I plan to make it as a desktop app with electron. So, I don't want to use server. Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that loading test.png from a local file violates the same origin policy, so the browser won't let you extract the merged image.

One option you could try is to load test.png from a data: url instead.

Another option might be to run a local server, as suggested in one of the comments. Since you want to run this in electron, I'd check first if actually running in electron has the same restrictions as running from file:

Comment: Hausein Thank you for your advice! I'd like to check the best practice for run with electron at first.